# Flutter StreamBuilder's snapshot does not have date despite sending it -- snapshot.data always set to initialData

Tags: flutter, stream

In this (small part of a app I'm building) I have a row of buttons which uses streams to select a behaviour (namely a time range to display data), that's working without problem. Then I want to change the selected action by setting the button color to say Colors.red. For this I use a Stream that take a value for a pressed button to rebuild the row of buttons with the appropriate colour.

For an unknown reason the snapshot.data is equal to initialData: whatever button I pressed. I checked that the stream value is the added value, and in order to make the StreamController behaves correctly I then replace the snapshot.data test by a test on var data = stream.listen((x) => data = x) and that works.

I just do not understand what's happening

flutter doctor  -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.2, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-FR)
    • Flutter version 1.17.2 at /usr/local/flutter
    • Framework revision 5f21edf8b6 (4 days ago), 2020-05-28 12:44:12 -0700
    • Engine revision b851c71829
    • Dart version 2.8.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jfb/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_242-b08)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.4.1, Build version 11E503a
    • CocoaPods version 1.9.1

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 • 17CF5871-B9F8-4739-B8BB-607807AD0530 • ios • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-4 (simulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Code of this part :

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:weight_trend/blocs/bloc_provider.dart';
import 'package:weight_trend/blocs/chart_bloc.dart';

var myStream = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
Stream stream = myStream.stream;
var data;  // normally should use snapshot.data

class ChartRangeSelectionButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: myStream.stream,
      initialData: 2,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        myStream.stream.listen((x) => data = x);
        print(snapshot.data);
        if (data == 1) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChartButton(title: '1W', buttonColor: Colors.red),
              ChartButton(title: '2W'),
              ChartButton(title: '3W'),
              ChartButton(title: '4W'),
            ],
          );
        } else if (data == 2) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChartButton(title: '1W'),
              ChartButton(title: '2W', buttonColor: Colors.red),
              ChartButton(title: '3W'),
              ChartButton(title: '4W'),
            ],
          );
        } else if (data == 3) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChartButton(title: '1W'),
              ChartButton(title: '2W'),
              ChartButton(title: '3W', buttonColor: Colors.red),
              ChartButton(title: '4W'),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChartButton(
                title: '1W',
              ),
              ChartButton(
                title: '2W',
              ),
              ChartButton(title: '3W'),
              ChartButton(title: '4W', buttonColor: Colors.red),
            ],
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class ChartButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChartButton({this.title, this.buttonColor = Colors.white});
  final String title;
  final buttonColor;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 60,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (title == '1W') {
            BlocProvider.of<ChartBloc>(context).inputEvent.add(ChartRange.one);
            myStream.sink.add(1);
          } else if (title == '2W') {
            BlocProvider.of<ChartBloc>(context).inputEvent.add(ChartRange.two);
            myStream.sink.add(2);
          } else if (title == '3W') {
            BlocProvider.of<ChartBloc>(context)
                .inputEvent
                .add(ChartRange.three);
            myStream.sink.add(3);
          } else if (title == '4W') {
            BlocProvider.of<ChartBloc>(context).inputEvent.add(ChartRange.four);
            myStream.sink.add(4);
          }
        },
        color: buttonColor,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        splashColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
        child: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you check snapshot.hasData ?

Comment: Yes it has always the same value namely initData

Comment: I posted a sample

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple example using your code and it seems to work ok:

```
2
2
3
1
```

Why are You using Bloc? It seems to me overkill for this type of things.
Just start simple.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "dart:async";

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ChartRangeSelectionButtons(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

var myStream = StreamController<int>.broadcast();
Stream stream = myStream.stream;
var data;  // normally should use snapshot.data

class ChartRangeSelectionButtons extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: myStream.stream,
      initialData: 2,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        //myStream.stream.listen((x) => data = x);
        print(snapshot.data);
        if (data == 1) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChartButton(title: '1W', buttonColor: Colors.red),
              ChartButton(title: '2W'),
              ChartButton(title: '3W'),
              ChartButton(title: '4W'),
            ],
          );
        } else if (data == 2) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChartButton(title: '1W'),
              ChartButton(title: '2W', buttonColor: Colors.red),
              ChartButton(title: '3W'),
              ChartButton(title: '4W'),
            ],
          );
        } else if (data == 3) {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChartButton(title: '1W'),
              ChartButton(title: '2W'),
              ChartButton(title: '3W', buttonColor: Colors.red),
              ChartButton(title: '4W'),
            ],
          );
        } else {
          return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              ChartButton(
                title: '1W',
              ),
              ChartButton(
                title: '2W',
              ),
              ChartButton(title: '3W'),
              ChartButton(title: '4W', buttonColor: Colors.red),
            ],
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class ChartButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChartButton({this.title, this.buttonColor = Colors.white});
  final String title;
  final buttonColor;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 60,
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          if (title == '1W') {
            //BlocProvider.of<ChartBloc>(context).inputEvent.add(ChartRange.one);
            myStream.sink.add(1);
          } else if (title == '2W') {
            //BlocProvider.of<ChartBloc>(context).inputEvent.add(ChartRange.two);
            myStream.sink.add(2);
          } else if (title == '3W') {
            //BlocProvider.of<ChartBloc>(context).inputEvent.add(ChartRange.three);
            myStream.sink.add(3);
          } else if (title == '4W') {
            //BlocProvider.of<ChartBloc>(context).inputEvent.add(ChartRange.four);
            myStream.sink.add(4);
          }
        },
        color: buttonColor,
        textColor: Colors.black,
        splashColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
        child: Text(title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```